# How to properly reuse karate-config.js and test-header.feature

Tags: karate

I am new to karate and have downloaded the karate-demo project and still reading through everything.  I recently joined a new project.  The project consists of numerous microservices, each its own project.  There is one feature file in each project with some differences between them.  The *karate-config file is the same* in each project. The *test-header scenario in the feature is the same* in each project.

As a solution to have one place to update a karate-config.js, is it bad practice to have a master karate-config.js file in a common test tools library/dependency and then have the local karate-config make a callOnce of the master karate.config?

Should we explore using json files to load the environment variables from each karate-config.js?

Can we reuse feature files with this architecture?

Is it best just to create java classes and call them from karate.config?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `classpath:karate-base.js` file in a common test tools library / dependency - that will act as a "master" source of variables.

Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-basejs

Comment: Thank you.  And as far as good or bad practices in CICD, wouldn't it be acceptable, if not better, to place feature files (like the authorization examples) in a common test tools library / dependency?

Comment: @CreatorOfID10TErrros you CAN. try it and see. use the `classpath:` prefix when referring to them.